# Detect winning in TicTacToe game.... in 'for' loop

Tags: android, arrays

I am new in android programming, i want to write a TicTacToe game for more learning, i followed

this article ([enter link description here](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/tictactoe-game-implementation/)) and changed a part of this article for better understanding ;)

My problem is in the validateGame() method, when i write cross in one horizontal line (i mean for

exapmle : coordinate[0][0]=X, coordinate[0](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/tictactoe-game-implementation/)=X, coordinate[0][2]=X), this method should run first

'for' loop and write in log and toast "horizontal x", but the method run second 'for' loop and

write in the log "vertical X".

Anyway, my method can to detect X or O but can not detect horizontal line or vertical line.
what is the problem? How can solved this? I can not understand validate_game() method in this

article and i want to write a method by myself ;) please help me.

Cheers.

```
public boolean validateGame(){
    Cell check=null;
    int counter=0;
    XSymbol xsym=new XSymbol();
    OSymbol osym=new OSymbol();

    //horizontal
    for(int i=0;i<coordinate.length;i++){
        check=null;
        for(int j=0;j<coordinate.length;j++){
            if(!coordinate[i][j].equals(check)||coordinate[i][j] instanceof Empty){
                check=coordinate[i][j];
                counter=0;
            }
            else
                counter++;
            if(counter==playerWin-1){
                if(coordinate[i][j].equals(xsym)){
                    winX=true;
                    Log.e("horizontal", "x");
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "HORIZONTAL X", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    winO=true;
                    Log.e("horizontal", "o");
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "HORIZONTAL O", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        counter=0;
    }

    //vertical
    for(int i=0;i<coordinate.length;i++){
        check=null;
        counter=0;
        for(int j=0;j<coordinate.length;j++){
            if(!coordinate[j][i].equals(check)||coordinate[j][i] instanceof Empty){
                check=coordinate[j][i];
                counter=0;
            }
            else
                counter++;
            if(counter==playerWin-1){
                if(coordinate[j][i].equals(osym)){
                    winO=true;
                    Log.e("vertical", "o");
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "VERTICAL O", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    winX=true;
                    Log.e("vertical", "x");
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "VERTIC" +"AL X", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        counter=0;
    }

    return false;
}
```

sorry on my poor english :P

UPDATE: I want to answer to my question and changed my question but the site not allowed :( anyway, i update my first answer.

I write your proposed method but my program not run right again :( I think my problem of the other 
thing. I write Cell and Empty and OSymbol and XSymbol class, please read and say to me, what is the 
problem??

your method, when i touch my screen for first click, toast shows 'horizontal O'!!!

Cell.java:

```
public abstract class Cell extends Point {
    public Cell(int x, int y) {
       super(x, y);
    }
    public Cell(){
       super();
    }
    abstract public void draw(Canvas g,Resources res, int x, int y, int w, int h);
 }
```

Empty.java:

```
public class Empty extends Cell {
    public Empty(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
    }
    public Empty(){
        super();
    }    
    public void draw(Canvas g, Resources res, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        Bitmap im = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.blank);
        g.drawBitmap(im, null, new Rect(x*w, y*h, (x*w)+w, (y*h)+h), new Paint());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Empty) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

XSymbol.java:

```
public class XSymbol extends Cell {
    public XSymbol(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
    }
    public XSymbol(){
        super();
    }
    public void draw(Canvas g, Resources res, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        Bitmap im = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.x);
        g.drawBitmap(im, null, new Rect(x*w, y*h, (x*w)+w, (y*h)+h), new Paint());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof XSymbol) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

OSymbol.java:

```
public class OSymbol extends Cell { 
   public OSymbol(int x, int y) {
      super(x, y);
   }
   public OSymbol(){
      super();
   }
   public void draw(Canvas g, Resources res, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
      Bitmap im = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.o);
      g.drawBitmap(im, null, new Rect(x*w, y*h, (x*w)+w, (y*h)+h), new Paint());
   }
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (obj instanceof OSymbol) {
         return true;
       } else {
          return false;
       }
    }
 }
```

Game.java:

```
 public class Game extends View{
    .
    .
    . 
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
     int x_touch=(int)(event.getX()/(this.getWidth()/x));
     int y_touch=(int)(event.getY()/(this.getHeight()/y));
     drawImage(x_touch,y_touch);
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
} 
    public void drawImage(int x_touch,int y_touch){
    Cell cell=null;
    if(whatDrawn){
    cell=new XSymbol(x_touch,y_touch);
    whatDrawn=false;
    }else{
    cell=new OSymbol(x_touch,y_touch);
    whatDrawn=true;
    }
        coordinate[x_touch][y_touch]=cell;
    validate();
     }
     public boolean validate(){
    XSymbol xsym=new XSymbol();
    OSymbol osym=new OSymbol();

    boolean xWin=false;
    boolean oWin=false;

    for(int i=0;i<coordinate.length;i++){
        boolean won=true;
        for(int j=1;j<coordinate.length;j++){
            if(!coordinate[i][j-1].equals(coordinate[i][j])){
                won=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(won){
            if(coordinate[i][0].equals(xsym)){
                xWin=true;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "horizontal X", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                oWin=true;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "horizontal O", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }


    //vertical
    for(int i=0;i<coordinate.length;i++){
        boolean won=true;
        for(int j=1;j<coordinate.length;j++){
            if(!coordinate[j-1][i].equals(coordinate[j][i])){
                won=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(won){
            if(coordinate[0][i].equals(xsym)){
                xWin=true;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "vertical X", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                oWin=true;
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "vertical O", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }


    return false;
    }
        .
        .
        .
     }
```

Sorry for long question :( 
Thanks.
Cheers

Comment: are you sure this `coordinate[i][j].equals(xsym)` is supposed to work ? (i.e. have you overriden the equals method?)

Comment: thanks for quick reply, yes i have overriden equals(Object obj) method in XSymbol,OSymbol,Empty and Cell class and my program can detect that i write X or O in cell of screen .

Answer (score -1):

Your check variable is not properly initialized. you should break when you test for difference:

```
//horizontal
for(int i=0;i<coordinate.length;i++){
    boolean won = true;
    for(int j=1;j<coordinate.length;j++){
        if (!coordinates[i][j].equals(coordinates[i][j-1]) {
            won = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (won) {
         if(coordinate[i][0].equals(xsym)){
             xWin = true;
         } else {
             oWin = true;
         }
    }
}
```

In English, this reads as:

For each line, as soon as a cell is different from the previous cell, it is not a winning line.

If it is a winning line, the winner is the player who put a symbol on the first cell of the line.

Comment: Thanks. Why you write 'break' in end of 'if'?? I don't understand 2 last sentence :( please explain simple. If you can, my code fix.Thank you ;)

Comment: the test breaks because a cell is different from the previous cell, which implies the line is not a winning line, which means testing further is unnecessary (although won = false is sufficient)

Comment: njzk2, I update my answer, i write your proposed method but my program not run right again. Please read and help me. Thanks.